# SAS workspace server terminates unexpectantly

Tags: sas

We have a large dataset 100M rows. I have a need to aggregate the data for some summaries. We are currently doing this through Proc SQL. When I run this, the process runs for some period of time and then unexpectantly, the process terminates in the workspace server. This leaves EG hanging until it eventually errors (hours later).

**What might be causing this?** I monitor the box and we aren't maxing out resources.

**How can I troubleshoot?** There are no logs being produced by the workspace server.

Comment: Are there some preliminary parts of the aggregation that you can do with data steps?  PROC SQL doesn't produce much in the way of logs but if you have a couple of data steps, you can see where things are failing.

Comment: Can you test the process on a dataset with a few thousand rows, to verify whether the problem is the code or the quantity?  Can you post your code to SO?  It's going to be hard to tell exactly what's wrong without seeing code, other than generic advice like "Verify you have enough RAM in OPTION MEMSIZE; for the summary".

Comment: You could also try `proc summary` as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If the process is running on another DB, via ODBC pass through or SAS/Access, the trace option may be helpful for debugging (will show you in the log exactly what is being executed)

```
options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog nostsuffix;
```

to remove:

```
options sastrace=none;
```

Regarding Workspace Logging - this may not be switched on.  You can do this via SMC, or manually (see [this guide](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-switch-on-workspace-logging.html)).

Can you give more details of the code being executed, your environment, etc etc?

Another option might be to run on a smaller number of observations (inobs=100).  If this still doesn't work, try modifying your query - removing tables one at a time..